# Can I stop hyperref from showing bookmarks in a side bar?

Tags: hyperref

I have a file I have been working on for two weeks now, and just added `hyperref`.  It is a small document and I really do not need the table of contents displayed as a sidebar next to the pdf when I PDFLaTexify it.  I see how to set `hyperref` to show that sidebar with option `bookmarksopen=true` or `false`.

But is there a way to get it to leave the sidebar out altogether?

Comment: use `\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}` to disable booksmarks. see also the `hyperref` manual on page 18. otherwise it is depending on the PDF viewer your using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As naphaneal says in a comment, you can use `\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}` to disable booksmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your document class, passing `bookmarks=false` to `hyperref` might not be sufficient. For instance, KOMA document classes (e.g. `scrartcl`) manage their own bookmarks via the `bookmarks` package. This will lead to the following output in the log file:

> Using `bookmark' together with `hyperref' is recommended,
> because of handling of possible bookmark level gaps.
> You can avoid loading `bookmark' with KOMA-Script option
> `bookmarkpackage=false' before \begin{document} and
> you can avoid this message adding:
>   \usepackage{bookmark}
> before \begin{document} on input line 24.

So, to prevent KOMA-Script from creating bookmarks, pass the `bookmarkpackage=false` option when loading the document class.